# dynamic changing element style using JS - Joomla ChronoForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, mootools

Please help me with a form I'm trying to do.

I have a dropdown select, all the options in the < select > have ID's, for example: one option has id="hide_me", other option has id="hide_none".

Here is the JS that I have for the form:

```
<?php
$script = "window.addEvent('domready', function() {
$('recipe').addEvent('change', function(event) {
  if ( $('recipe')document.getElementById('hide_it').selected === true ) {
     $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '1');
     $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '1');
  }
});
$('recipe').addEvent('change', function(event) {
  if ( $('recipe')document.getElementById('hide_none').selected === true ) {
     $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '0');
     $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '0');
  }
});
});
";
$doc =&JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration( $script );
?>
```

"recipe" is the name and ID of the dropdown < select >

At the moment it's giving me a JS error like "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", could somebody help me please with this

Answer (score 2):

your generated js looks like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $('recipe').addEvent('change', function(event) {
        if ($('recipe') document.getElementById('hide_it').selected === true) {
            $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '1');
            $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '1');
        }
    });
    $('recipe').addEvent('change', function(event) {
        if ($('recipe') document.getElementById('hide_none').selected === true) {
            $('hide_me1').setStyle('opacity', '0');
            $('hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

if you use something like jslint / jshint or even paste in jsfiddle and press the jslint button, it will immediately report the problems.

however:

`$('recipe') document.getElementById('hide_it').selected === true)` makes no sense. I guess you are trying to read the option with id hide_it that is a child of recipe?

its the wrong thing to do but this would be something like:

```
$('recipe').getElement('#hide_it').get('selected'); // pointless as by id alone is faster and id is meant to be unique
document.getElement('#receipe #hide_id').get('selected'); // also pointless like above, alt syntax that allows you to combine selectors.
$('hide_it').get('selected'); // works but also wrong, not how you work with selects.
```

The correct way to obtain the value of a `select` with mootools will be simply:

```
$('receip').addEvent('change', function(){
    // within this function, this === $('recipe');
    var opacity = this.get('value') === 'hide_it' ? 1 : 0;
    $$('#hide_me1,#hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', opacity);

    // w/o a reference you could do in a single line:
    $$('#hide_me1,#hide_me2').setStyle('opacity', +(this.get('value') == 'hide_it'));
});
```

this is still somewhat ineffective as it will lookup the 2 hide_me els every change event when they are probably static.

you should also stop using ids and pattern this based around classes, ids does not scale well.